# How to limit number of digits using regex but allow zeros in front

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to limit the matches to 7 digits at most, but at the same time I want to allow zeroes in front of the number. Right now it's allowing numbers such as 0, 1, 12, 123, 1234, 12345, 123456, 1234567 which is expected. This is the problem, I also want to find a match for numbers such as 0001234567 but not 12345678. This is the regex I'm using:

```
/^[1-9][0-9]{0,6}$|^0$/g
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do it:

```
/^0*[1-9][0-9]{0,6}$/
```

It allows any number of leading zeroes.

Comment: @Simon - I thought you wanted to match exactly seven digits (plus any number of leading zeros). That's what your question seems to say. Did you mean *up to* seven digits?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder i meant up to seven digits

Answer (score 3):

Try this `/^0*[0-9]{7}$/`

- 0001234567 - pass
- 1234567 - pass
- 12345678 - error
- 12345 - error

Comment: `[0-9]` => `\d`. Both work, the latter is perhaps somewhat more idiomatic.

Comment: Sadly, the OP meant *up to* seven digits, not exactly. (I read it as exactly too.)

Comment: i'm sorry if my question wasn't clear. i updated the question already for future reference. you still have my upvote

Answer (score 1):

As you als want to match 0, you might also use an alternation to match 1+ more zeroes as well

```
^(?:0*[1-9]\d{0,6}|0+)$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/WRwOZf/1)

You might also use parseInt and check for the string length

```js
const limitNumbers = s => parseInt(s, 10).toString().length < 8;
const strings = [
  "0",
  "1",
  "12",
  "123",
  "1234",
  "12345",
  "123456",
  "1234567",
  "0001234567",
  "12345678",
];

strings.forEach(s => console.log(`${s}: ${limitNumbers(s)}`))
```